# Xamarin, Binding Enum to ListView

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have a list of `Programs` and I binding it to `Xamarin forms ListView`

```
public class Program
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Color { set; get; }
    public LayoutAlignment LangDirection { set; get; }
}
```

`Text` and `Color` works fine but `LangDirection` of type  ***LayoutAlignment*** not **working!**

```
    <ListView       x:Name="ItemsListView" 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <StackLayout Padding="10">
                                        <Label TextColor="{Binding Color}" 
                                                Text="{Binding Text}" 
                                                FontSize="16" 
                                               HorizontalOptions="{Binding LangDirection}"
                                               />
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
   </ListView>
```

And no error occur

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44565205/how-to-bind-horizontaloptions-property-of-label-in-xamarin-forms

Comment: This works thanks @Jason